# 500 Error for wp-admin area

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Whenever I try to login to the admin area I get a 500 Error:

> The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition.
>
> *************/~bulletne/wp-admin/profile.php (port 80)
>
> Please forward this error screen to ************'s WebMaster.

The folder permissions are set to 755, files 644. and the .htaccess log looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~bulletne/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~bulletne/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that's the REALLY weird thing... the error doesn't show up there

Comment: Have you [enabled `WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to display all error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing to do is *backup your database and files*.

Try renaming your `wp-content/plugins` directory to something like `xplugins` and see if you can get in. If you can, then one (or more) of your plugins is blowing up early in the load process. To hunt down the offender, create a new `plugins` directory and move your plugins back in one at a time, reloading the dashboard after each move.

If the above does not solve your problem, then you have deeper issues. I would consider creating a new install of WP (using latest stable) and then import the saved DB into it using something like phpMyAdmin. If that blows things up then you have a corrupt DB issue. If not, try reintroducing your theme. Still OK? Bring in your plugins.

Good luck.